# Conductivity in Semi Conductor With band structure

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, fermis-golden-rule

I am trying to figure out how to compute the conductivity(or gain) in a semi conductor (excited by light at optical frequency $E=\hbar\omega$) using its band structure and matrix momentum element.

This research paper "*Modal Gain in a Semiconductor Nanowire Laser With Anisotropic Bandstructure*" suggests the following approach :

Defining dimensionless momentum element $\tilde{p_\mathbf{k}}$ as : 
 $P\frac{m_0}{\hbar}\tilde{p_\mathbf{k}} = \left\langle \Psi^v_\mathbf{k} \left| \mathbf{p} \right| \Psi^c_\mathbf{k}\right\rangle$, where $\Psi^v_\mathbf{k}$ and $\Psi^c_\mathbf{k}$ are the wave functions of conduction band electron and valence band hole with wave vector $\mathbf{k}$ and P the Kane parameter (in $\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{p}$ theory), the conductivity tensor $\sigma_{ij}$ at a given optical energy $E=\hbar\omega$ can then be written as :

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{ij}(E)=\frac{P^2e^2}{8\pi^2\hbar  E_g}\int_{S(E)}\Sigma^{\mathbf{k}}_{ij}\frac{1-f_e(\mathbf{k})-f_h(\mathbf{k})}{|\nabla _{\mathbf{k}}E(\mathbf{k})|}dS
\end{equation}

Where $\Sigma^{\mathbf{k}}_{ij}=p_{\mathbf{k},i}p^*_{\mathbf{k},j}$ ( which is actually diagonal with $\Sigma^{\mathbf{k}}_{xx}=\Sigma^{\mathbf{k}}_{yy}\neq \Sigma^{\mathbf{k}}_{zz}$ in my case) and $E(\mathbf{k})$ the band structure of the semi conductor. $E_g=3.4 eV$ is the band gap and $f_e(\mathbf{k})$ and $f_v(\mathbf{k})$ are the Fermi Dirac statistic distribution of conduction band electrons and valence band holes with chemical potential $\mu_e=130meV$ and $\mu_v=-30meV$ respectively.

What I do not understand is :

**What do I take for the iso-energy surface S(E) and band structure $E(\mathbf{k})$?? Should I take that of the valence band or the conduction band or all pairs for which the gap energy $E=\hbar\omega$ (In this latter case, how do I compute the gradiant?)?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually the dispersion relation obtained from the sum of the valence hole and conduction electron dispersion relations 
$ E(\mathbf k) = E_h(\mathbf k) - E_e(\mathbf k)$.

This new dispersion relation has new iso-energy surfaces depending on $\mathbf k$. The gradient can also be computed $\nabla_{\mathbf k}E$ .